# Using Numpy and SciPy on Apache Pig

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, apache-pig

I want to write UDFs in Apache Pig. I'll be using Python UDFs. 
My issue is I have tons of data to analyse and need packages like NumPy and SciPy. Buy this they dont have Jython support I cant use them along with Pig.

Do we have a substitue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can stream through a (C)Python script that imports scipy.
I am for instance using this to cluster data inside bags, using import scipy.cluster.hierarchy

Comment: Thanks. So do you dump the data out and use hadoop streaming to do this ?